# html_styles_background-color change (HTML only, no CSS)

Tags: python, html

How can i get a background color to the text "Test" below?
I have tried the following:

```
<table style="background-color:powderblue;" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><hr /></td>
    <strong style="font-size: 35px;">Test</strong><br />
    <td><hr /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but the results is:

[image]

Does exist any solution with HTML only? CSS doesn not work with the enviroment i use.

Comment: Did you try to move `style="background-color:powderblue;"` to the `strong` element? Also, I'm intrigued to know on what environment CSS does not work.

Comment: I have tried, but in a wrong way:    <strong style="font-size: 35px;" "background-color:powderblue;">Test</strong><br /> The background will be ignored. The enviroment is python and plotly.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actually supposed to be a table, this works:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
      <strong style="font-size: 35px; background-color: powderblue;">Test</strong>
      <br />
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I am baffled why you have a `<strong>` tag with a `font-size` of `35px`. You may as well use a `<h1>`:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
    <h1 style="background-color: powderblue;">Test</h1>
    <br />
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Replying to your comment, the `<h1>` can be given a `lightgray` background like this:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
    <div style="background-color: lightgray">
      <strong style="font-size: 35px; background-color: powderblue;">Test</strong>
      <br />
    </div>
    <td>
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But usually, all children in a `<table>`, including the `<strong>` element, must be wrapped in a `<td>` element (except for table headings, they should be wrapped in `<th>`).

Comment: Thank you, it works. I would like to have the text "Test" in such a colored field as made with: <hr size="5" color="lightgray">. How could be achieved it?

Comment: I mean not background of the text, but background of the field, where the text is to display.

Comment: Something like: <hr size="40" color="lightgray" >Test<>

Comment: @Essegn updated my answer, check the last code snippet

Comment: Great Aryan, it works now as i wanted to have it. Thank you for your time.